# QGIS updated to 3.22 - cannot open project on LTR 3.16 - is saving using the "old" framework possible?

Tags: qgis, installation

A collegue updated his QGIS to the newest Version (3.22) and saved a project there (.qgz). Since two days we couldn´t open the project on the computers using the LTR Version (3.16) anymore.

Is there any possibility of "downgrading" the .qgz again so that we all can use 3.16 until there is a new LTR? Or will the only solution be to just install the newest version on all computers?

Comment: When opening a project from an old version, a meaningful information message is shown, similar to `INFO    Project file is older : This project file was saved by QGIS version 3.10.10-A Coruña. When saving this project file, QGIS will update it to version 3.16.11-Hannover, possibly rendering it useless for older versions of QGIS.`

Comment: ... and I am not aware of a way to downgrade projects. That being said, if it is worth it, you can always unzip the project and look at its plain text content and try to replicate it in another version of QGIS

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was able to solve our problem by retrieving a backup of the qgz from last week.. luckily there wasn't much change since then and it worked immediately.